# Set range on x, sort and count in Pandas

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dataframe, and I want to set several ranges for x in a certain column. For, example I have 1000 entries in column C with different values (from 0 to 100). I want to sort the values from min to max, divide in parts like: 0 to 10, 10 to 20 etc, and now count how many of these values I have in every part.

(0 to 10) I have 4 values (I don't care which ones exactly)
(10 to 20) I have 22 values
etc...

Answer (score 1):

Should probably be on StackOverflow but I'm also new so I have no idea how to move it...

Anyway this sounds like you basically want a histogram, which pandas can do: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

If you then want to turn the hist into text, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992644/turn-pandas-dataframe-of-strings-into-histogram

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Even while links still work, the content can't be indexed to help people find the solution.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.